# Spacing around Parentheses with \left \right

Tags: math-mode, spacing

When having an equation like `\delta(t-nT_\mathrm{s})` it clearly reads as a function with an argument:

[image: \delta(t-nT_\mathrm{s})]

But having big parentheses with `\left` and `\right` as in `X\left(f-\frac{n}{T_\mathrm{s}}\right)` reads as a product due to the extra space.
I know this is due to `\left` and `\right` inserting a bit of space but what is the canonical way around that? To me this just looks like a product; not a function:

[image: \frac{P(f)}{T_\mathrm{s}} \cdot \sum\displaylimits_{n=-\infty}^\infty X\left(f-\frac{n}{T_\mathrm{s}}\right)]

Comment: Maybe try `\Bigl(` and `\Bigr)`?

Comment: But this is not dynamic. It works in this specific case (the scale is exactly reproduced by `\biggl(` and `\biggr)`), but the editor needs to pic the right scale then and it is easy to get it off by one. Is there an automatic/dynamic size solution that is not hacky?

Comment: See the `mleftright` package. I would not worry too much about it

Comment: This is perfect, thanks :) This is the correct solution.